# How to refer to gradle configuration set in gradle.properties with Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle.properties

I'm trying to adopt the Kotlin Gradle DSL. I have a `gradle.properties` with, among other things:

```
slf4jVersion=2.0.0-alpha1
```

I declare the dependency in `build.gradle.kts` with:

```
implementation( name = "slf4j-api",
  group = "org.slf4j", version = project.properties["slf4jVersion"].toString())
```

Yes, it works, but it also smells. The issue is the ugliness of `project.properties["slf4jVersion"].toString()`

Shouldn't I be able to just write `slf4jVersion`? It makes standard configuration look like a custom hack. What is the canonical and succinct way to keep version numbers together in a separate file with the Kotlin Gradle DSL?

Answer (score 2):

You can access project properties via delegated properties.

In your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
val slf4jVersion: String by project
implementation(name = "slf4j-api", group = "org.slf4j", version = slf4jVersion)
```

Official sample: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/blob/3c977388f78bdcff1f7ed466e8d27feb5bf32275/samples/project-properties/build.gradle.kts#L14

Comment: So every entry in gradle.properties needs a matching val delegation? This looks nicer but is also more fragile. I do appreciate the option, though. Maybe there could be a better way to declare the version numbers than in gradle.properties.

Comment: @TravisWell same question... have you found a solution?

Comment: @Arst no. now I just put versions in the gradle file instead of using a properties file. with a naming convention, it's easy to grep versions from the `build.gradle.kts` files, and a one-line bash script uses `sed -i` to update versions.